# CRON with settings from multiple stores

Tags: magento-2.1, configuration, cron

In Magento 2, what is the cleanest way to have the same CRON job run for every store, and pull relevant configuration settings from the appropriate store?

Would it be to add a loop inside `Vendor/Module/Cron/Job.php`, `execute` method, checking every store, and setting `$this->storeManager->setCurrentStore` at the top of the method?

Followed by,

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue('...', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply Inject the StoresConfig class in your Cron model class constructor, and read store config values with getStoresConfigByPath($path) for all stores. This will return the config values with the associated store ids:

Class File: /vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoresConfig.php

```
public function getStoresConfigByPath($path)
{
    $stores = $this->_storeManager->getStores(true);
    $storeValues = [];
    /** @var $store \Magento\Store\Model\Store */
    foreach ($stores as $store) {
        try {
            $value = $this->_config->getValue($path, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $store->getCode());
            $storeValues[$store->getId()] = $value;
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            // Store doesn't really exist, so move on.
            continue;
        }
    }
    return $storeValues;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the following procedure to setup cron in Magento2  :

**app/code/Vender/ModuleName/etc/cron_groups.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/cron_groups.xsd">
    <group id="cron_group_name">
        <schedule_generate_every>1</schedule_generate_every>
        <schedule_ahead_for>4</schedule_ahead_for>
        <schedule_lifetime>2</schedule_lifetime>
        <history_cleanup_every>10</history_cleanup_every>
        <history_success_lifetime>60</history_success_lifetime>
        <history_failure_lifetime>600</history_failure_lifetime>
    </group>
</config>
```

Create crontab.xml :
**app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/crontab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="cron_group_name">
        <job name="cronname_api" instance="Vendor\ModuleName\Cron\Cron" method="execute">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
        .......................
        ......................
    </group>
</config>
```

Create Cron.php
**app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/Cron/Cron.php**

```
  <?php
    namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Cron;

    class Cron
    {
    public function execute()
    {
    // Paste your logic for multiple stores
   // Given example cron will run every minute execute() function 
    }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, but how would I run particular code in execute() for every store, using system.xml values from each store?

Comment: As you mentioned above you can use  ScopeConfigInterface , also define multiple jobs for each of your store at by using store code or Id its up to you, As I don't know what logic you actually want to deploy inside the cron's , But I can say you pick one of option and it will work  for all conditions without blocker , either   ScopeConfigInterface  Or Multiple Cron Jobs .