# schedule cron on every night at 9pm

Tags: cron, crontab

I have written job code on `crontab.xml`

```
<job name="vendor_out_for_delivery_notifiation" instance="Bakeway\VendorNotification\Helper\Data" method="sendPushNotificationForUpcomingOrderCron">
        <schedule>0 */21 * * </schedule>
</job>
```

I have given 9pm of every night but its not working entries is not going in to `cron_schedule` table.

I have created custom group of this cron.

```
<group id="vendor_notification_cron_group">


php bin/magento cron:run --group="vendor_notification_cron_group"
```

Please reply if you have any solution.

Comment: You can check this answer [Cron setup code](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/210470/cron-with-settings-from-multiple-stores/210472#210472) kindly match your code by this code.

Answer (score 1):

There is a star missing. Try:

```
<schedule>0 */21 * * *</schedule>
```

or better:

```
<schedule>0 21 * * *</schedule>
```

Comment: Yes , i had tried same but it is not working cron is not working @9pm.

Comment: May be its bug of Magento 2